# The requested Payment Method is not available

Tags: error, payment-methods, backend

When creating an order at the backend, we get `The requested Payment Method is not available!"`. Our exception is thrown at `/app/code/core/Mage/Payment/Model/Info.php` in function `getMethodInstance`.

The payment method is working at regular online orders, but not via the backend.
We have this problem after updating to Magento 1.9.1.1 .

I believe that `$instance` is set, but I am not able to find `setInfoInstance` method to debug this further. Where can I find it?

The requested payment method is in the list of the active payment methods.
Is it possible, that an other non used payment method is responsible for this trouble Then: How can I find out, which payment method causes the issue?

Also m2epro import has the same problems.

Comment: did you update any modules?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following was working:

app/code/core/Mage/Payment/Model/Info.php

```
public function getMethodInstance()
{
    if (!$this->hasMethodInstance()) {
        if ($this->getMethod()) {
            $instance = Mage::helper('payment')->getMethodInstance($this->getMethod());
            if ($instance) {

                $instance->setInfoInstance($this);

                $this->setMethodInstance($instance);

                return $instance;
            }
        } else {

            $instance = Mage::helper('payment')->getMethodInstance('banktransfer');
            if ($instance) {

                $instance->setInfoInstance($this);

                $this->setMethodInstance($instance);

                return $instance;
            }
        }
        Mage::throwException(Mage::helper('payment')->__('The requested Payment Method is not available!!'));
    }

    return $this->_getData('method_instance');
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Not all payment methods allow ordering from the backend. However, since you say it was working prior to an update, it's unlikely that is the problem.

But, just in case. If you have a peek at

`app/code/core/Mage/Payment/Modal/Method/Purchaseorder.php`

you should see something like:

```
protected $_canUseInternal = true;
protected $_canUseCheckout = false;
```

You could copy this to your local code pool and modify the booleans to allow ordering from the backend (if this is your issue).

Comment: Seems to be correct, when I debug the code: