# The requested Payment Method is not available on custome module

Tags: magento-1.9, onepage-checkout, payment

I am shortening the one page checkout page as my store will not have payment option and shipping selection option. I am following below blog

http://excellencemagentoblog.com/blog/2011/10/17/magento-onestep-checkout-remove-payment-method-step/

Everything works fine till place order after the review section. Upon clicking on the place order button I am getting below error

> The requested Payment Method is not available.

My controller section to set payment mode is as below

```
$quote = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote();
                        $methodCode = 'free';


                        if ($quote->isVirtual()) {
                            $quote->getBillingAddress()->setPaymentMethod($methodCode);
                        } else {
                            $quote->getShippingAddress()->setPaymentMethod($methodCode);
                        }
                        $quote->save();
```

And the free shipping mode enabled also.

I referred below question posted before:

[The requested Payment Method is not available](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/71780/the-requested-payment-method-is-not-available)

It is not solving my issue. No system.lo captured also.

Comment: Could you try `free_free` as method code? I seem to remember it' should be something like that. Also, try placing an order with all steps enabled and check what the code for payment and shipping is in the `sales_flat_order` table

Comment: @SanderMangel I can see shipping method name in `sales_flat_order` table, cant see payment mode name on that table?

Comment: The code is "freeshipping" for free shipping

Comment: free payment method is available only when order total is 0, verify that you are fulfilling this condition first.

Comment: @SanderMangel your trick works, I enabled all the modules and made one transaction. Then I didn't know how to get payment code. So I wrote a code `$order = new Mage_Sales_Model_Order(); $order->loadByIncrementId($order_id); $payment_method = $order->getPayment()->getMethodInstance()->getCode();` I found the code and applied. It works fine now.

Comment: @Prateek yes you are right, so I installed cash on delivery extension and used the code.

Comment: @version.beta I've added my comment as answer in case you want to accept it as the answer that solved it. If not please post your own answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try free_free as method code. I seem to remember it should be something like that.

Also, try placing an order with all steps enabled and check what the code for payment and shipping is in the sales_flat_order table.