# The requested Payment Method is not available. Force Set Method

Tags: magento-1.7, payment-methods

I have purchase order set as the only active payment method. Checkout throws the "requested method not available" error. I want to force set the payment method when it doesn't have a method set.

I'd like to do this in the theme, not the core.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found and ended up using the answer from this post: [The requested Payment Method is not available](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/71780/the-requested-payment-method-is-not-available?rq=1) to "remind" the checkout process that the payment method is purchaseorder. This allowed the order to proceed, generate notification emails, and redirect to the success page.

NOTE: I used this as a temporary fix. I will be moving a copy of the site to a dev server, and finding the actual issue and resolving it without modifying the core files.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to update code, of course do not modify core files directly.

This is the base file:
core/Mage/Checkout/controllers/OnepageController.php

This is the function that sets the payment method:
function savePaymentAction()

Change this line:

> $data = $this->getRequest()->getPost('payment', array());

To something like this:

> $data = array('method'=>'purchase_order');

You will need to check whether the name 'purchase_order' is correct.

If you are trying to skip the payment section then you can put the code earlier in the process, making sure to save the data:
$result = $this->getOnepage()->savePayment($data);

Comment: I modified OnepageController.php to see if it worked. It did not. It threw the error prior to the order review, instead of after, and it didn't submit the order. Thoughts?

Comment: Did you check whether 'purchase_order' is the correct name?

Inspect the page for something like:
`<input id="p_method_cashondelivery" value="cashondelivery" type="radio" name="payment[method]" title="Cash On Delivery" onclick="payment.switchMethod('cashondelivery')" autocomplete="off">`
Here the name would be 'cashondelivery'

Comment: I did check - purchaseorder (no underscore separator) is the correct method name. Using purchaseorder, it still throws the "not available" error.

Comment: Does this option come up in the checkout?
Can you select in manually and progress?
Could you link to the site?

Comment: Purchase order option does come up in checkout. And processes the order. It is submitted, as pending, correctly and shows in admin. However, rather than a success message, it shows "method not available error" triggered in /core/Mage/Payment/Model/Info.php

Comment: Sorry - hit send too early - the site is a login required catalog. We use AITOC for checkout fields extension, but their support has reviewed and we both agree that the issue occurs even with their extension disabled.

Comment: This is the exception log, each time checkout occurs: http://pastebin.com/eiwgY4kK

Comment: The pastebin link does not work :/